# Periodogram (TSA In R) can't find correct frequency

Tags: r, time-series, fft

I'm trying to process a sinusoidal time series data set:

[image: Time Series Data]
I am using this code in R:

```
library(readxl)
library(stats)
library(matplot.lib)
library(TSA)

Data_frame<-read_excel("C:/Users/James/Documents/labssin2.xlsx")

# compute the Fourier Transform
p = periodogram(Data_frame$NormalisedVal)

dd = data.frame(freq=p$freq, spec=p$spec)
order = dd[order(-dd$spec),]
top2 = head(order, 5)
# display the 2 highest "power" frequencies
top2
time = 1/top2$f
time
```

However when examining the frequency spectrum the frequency (which is in Hz) is ridiculously low ~ 0.02Hz, whereas it should have one much larger frequency of around 1Hz and another smaller one of 0.02Hz (just visually assuming this is a sinusoid enveloped in another sinusoid).

[image: FFT of series]

Might be a rather trivial problem, but has anyone got any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit 1: Using

```
result <- abs(fft(df$Data_frame.NormalisedVal))
```

Produces what I am expecting to see.

[image: Second Fourier Trasform Attempt]

Edit2: As requested, text file with the output to dput(Data_frame).
http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1553266283956.txt

Comment: Post output of `dput(Data_frame)` in your question body. Otherwise it's missing a [MCVE] and will be closed.

Comment: Its absolutely enormous,  as In thousands of lines.

Comment: Then make it accessible at a web location.

Comment: Done, I have no idea what use itll be but there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [periodogram](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TSA/versions/1.2/topics/periodogram) function returns *normalized* frequencies in the [0,0.5] range, where 0.5 corresponds to the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), i.e. half your sampling rate. Since you appear to have data sampled at 60Hz, the spike at 0.02 would correspond to a frequency of 0.02*60 = 1.2Hz, which is consistent with your expectation and in the neighborhood of what can be seen in the data your provided (the bulk of the spike being in the range of 0.7-1.1Hz).

On the other hand, the x-axis on the last graph you show based on the `fft` is an index and not a frequency. The corresponding frequency should be computed according to the following formula:

```
f <- (index-1)*fs/N
```

where `fs` is the sampling rate, and `N` is the number of samples used by the `fft`. So in your graph the same 1.2Hz would appear at an index of ~31 assuming `N` is approximately 1500.

*Note*: the sampling interval in the data you provided is not quite constant and may affect the results as both `periodogram` and `fft` assume a regular sampling interval.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes a lot of sense. Is there any particular reason I'm only getting one specific frequency spike, when it seems the form of the data is sin(Ax)*sin(Bx)? Surely we would expect two peaks?

Comment: If you did have sin(Ax)*sin(Bx) you should indeed be able to see two peaks provided the frequency resolution is good enough to resolve them, which requires having enough samples in your observed window. That said, in the plot you've shown there isn't such distinct peaks but rather a bunch of energy in the 0.7-1.1Hz range.

Comment: Any idea why I could be getting NAs when I try to input a different array into the fft()? The data doesn't appear to be any different to other arrays that work correctly.

Comment: NAs in the input could do that. Otherwise I can't tell without more context. If you can provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example that could make another good question.